# Mock network request for unit test

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

I am using `JUnit4` and `Mockito` for unit test.
Here is the case:
I have a function that needs to be tested, while within this function it contains a network request, and now I want to mock the network request result.

```
void func(String param1, String param2){
    //there would be some validations for the params
    //...

    //then network request, here I want to mock the result
    String result = NetUtils.reqNetwork(param1, param2);

    //work with the result
    //...
}
```

Is this possible? Or maybe my test approach is kinds of unreasonable.

Comment: NetUtils.reqNetwork looks like a static method. You cannot mock a static method with Mockito. You have to use PowerMock on top of it.

Comment: @kswaughs Thanks for your reply, but some blogs indicate that PowerMock would change the byte-code to make it work to mock static functions, then is it safe for it to do that?

Comment: It is safe to use PowerMock. When you run your junit, it will start its own JVM and these mocked objects are loaded into this JVM only. So, No need to worry on this.

Comment: By making NetUtils instantiable, or by wrapping your call to NetUtils in an overridable helper method, you can replace the functionality without using PowerMock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With only Mockito, there is no way to mock out static method calls. My usual strategy to get around this is to either make these static classes instantiable, or make wrapper classes that are instantiable. Then you can mock those wrappers as usual.

Another option is to use [PowerMock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock), which is built on top of Mockito but provides the capability to mock out these static method calls, along with a host of other things like superclass constructors, final classes, etc.